# how to check the history of services names changed in oracle database server

Tags: database, oracle

I am using oracle 11g database. When I were connecting this DB i were using "test"
in service name. But someone has changed it. Can you please let me know how to find my latest service name of DB and also the history of person who has changed this service name?

Answer (score 0):

this how to find your service name...

```
select sys_context('userenv','service_name') from dual;
```

I am not sure If you can know who change that .

Comment: Thanks moudiz, i tried your solution but it is not working. :(.

Comment: what the error occured ? why it didnt work ? i tested locally and it was good

Comment: It worked but whatever the service name it returned is not working . It is still giving wrong service name configuration.

Comment: maybe because someone has change it ?